# how to make a statement with two verbs

Tags: sentence

私はにほんごとごべんきょします

i would like to say i came here to study or learn Japanese (language) and to play go. the best i have come up with is above which says to study both; i know how to say each sentence separately how i want but cant seem to figure out how to combine them as it would us two verbs. any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If these are not necessarily the only two things you came here to do, or if you do these repeatedly, you could use the representative (-たり) form of the verbals:

> 私はにほんごとごべんきょします

-> 私は日本語を勉強したり、碁をしたりします。

> i would like to say i came here to study or learn Japanese (language) and to play go

私は日本語{にほんご}を勉強{べんきょう}したり、碁{ご}をしたりするために、ここに来{き}ました。(or, depending on the situation, ここに来たんです。)

You could also invert it like: ここに来たのは日本語{にほんご}を勉強{べんきょう}したり、碁{ご}をしたりするためです。

The representative might not cover every situation in which you're talking about doing two activities. But it sounds like it could be used in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the `〜ながら` sentence structure. So, in your case, it would be

`私はごをやりながら日本語を勉強しています`

`ごをやりながら` = `while playing go`

`日本語を勉強しています` = `study japanese language`

The link below explains a bit further into the sentence structure.

http://maggiesensei.com/2013/06/26/%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8C%E3%82%89nagara-from-facebook-mini-lesson/

Source: I used to study japanese language in Tokyo for a year plus.

Comment: I think the OP's means "I am learning to play go and learning to speak Japanese", not "learning to speak Japanese while playing go"

Answer (score 2):

You can use a conjunction また like 私はここに日本語を勉強しに、また、碁をやりに来ました。You may omit また.

Your sentence needs a bit correction like 私はにほんごとごをべんきょうします, which means "I study Japanese language and the game of go.".

Comment: 打つの方は適切ではないですか？

Comment: We say 碁を打つ, 碁をやる and 碁をする.

Answer (score 0):

Normally this is achieved by turning one of the verbs into the continuous –te form:

```
わたしはここに日本語を勉強して[囲碁]{いご}をやるために来ました。
```

You can replace やる with する for politeness.

Alternatively, you can use the ～り suffix but it's better to save it for cases in which you enumerate many, many things:

```
日本語を勉強したり囲碁をするためにここに来ました。
```

Note that in both cases, the を particle is mandatory.